# How to attach a variable name to .getSheetByName()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a series of sheets within a larger spreadsheet, and when I'm testing this, I need a reset function so I don't manually have to go through and delete each one. Three of the names are static, so I just have:

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Schedule'), true); 
spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
```

but a few of them change based on a variable. The name of the sheet is always "Session __" with __ changing by an integer value. This is what I tried,

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Inputs'), true);  
  var sessions = spreadsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();  
  for(i=0; i<=session; i++) {  
   var name = "Session {i+1}";  
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name));  
   spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();   
  }
```

(where the inputs sheet has the total number of sessions in cell B2)

but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: To create a string from a string and a number, use `+` (`var name = "Session " + (i + 1);`) or a template literal (```var name = `Session ${i + 1}`;```), but unless you're using the updated Google Apps Script that's based on V8, you can't use a template literal.

Comment: You can  use Utilities.formatString();But the V8 has been working pretty well for me so it might be time to switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Inputs');  
  var sessions=sh.getRange('B2').getValue();  
  for(var i=0;i<sessions;i++) {  
   var name="Session " + i+1
   ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name));   
  }
}
```